# Manipulação String postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, regex

Gostaria de manipular uma `String` com `regexp_replace` da seguinte maneira:

String para manipular:

```
'TESTE <<TESTE1>> TESTE <<TESTE2>>'
```

String depois da função:

```
'TESTE TESTE'
```

Tentei da seguinte maneira:

```
select regexp_replace('TESTE <<TESTE1>> TESTE <<TESTE2>>', '<<.*>>','')
```

porém retorna apenas o `'TESTE'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize a regex:

```
<<.*?>>
```

Irá casar tudo que estiver entre os sinais de `<<` e `>>` (inclusive os sinais).

Mas use também a flag `'g'` (global) para substituir todas as ocorrências (caso contrário irá substituir apenas a primeira):

```
select regexp_replace('TESTE <<TESTE1>> TESTE <<TESTE2>>', '<<.*?>>','','g')
```

**[Veja no SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/3f2fb/5)**